# read in a csv file with R not automatically converting the fields to numbers

Tags: r, csv

I need to read in a csv-file with R like the following:

"BITS";"TEXT"

"111111111111111010001010111111111111111111111111111";"abc"
"111111100011111111111111111111100000001111111111111";"xyz"

I read it in with:
my_data <- read.csv(filename, header=TRUE, sep=";")

If I now print my_data the value for "BITS" is "Inf", I guess because it is converted to a number. But I need it as a string value. How can I do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I solved it... numerals="no.loss" helps:

read.csv(filename, header=TRUE, sep=";", numerals="no.loss")